# Firewall and Torrent

Tags: ssh, vpn, firewall, port, bittorrent

I use my university internet network and all incoming connection is blocked on every port.(they use netasq firewall) They have no other restrictions which stops me from using a torrent client. Using torrent is **NOT** against university network policy but they restrict all incoming port just for security reasons.

Is there any way, I can use torrent in this situation?

can VPN be a solution here? (I understand VPN very little but I think it won't work)

can SSH be a solution?

Mainly, I need to know, **can torrent work if all incoming connection is blocked**? Is there any way to initiate the session beforehand so that **I get a open port in NAT table**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been successfully answered here.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77334/firewall-and-torrent
thank you. VPN solution is working and they actually used deep packet inspection.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using utorrent as your torrent client you can change incoming port in `Options[Menu] > Preferences > Connection > Listening Port` and modify the default port used for incoming connections.